# Hibernate Auto Increment in SQLite

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, auto-increment, create-table

I just started learning hibernate and its looking good. I am just stuck with creating a column in a table with auto increment property. Here is how I defined my column in my class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name="program_id")
protected Integer programid;
```

The problem here is when the sql query is created it returns an error because the query is incorrect for SQLite. Here is the generated query:

```
create table program (program_id integer not null auto_increment....)
```

You see it is written as **auto_increment** instead of **AUTOINCREMENT** (ignore case) I already tried Identity and still returns an incorrect sql query.

Is there a correct "strategy" in the annotation to approach this? or is there another setup to have the correct sql query?

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
@Id
@Column(name = "program_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic
protected Integer programid;
```